# Evaluating equality in perl using elements taken from an array ref

Tags: arrays, perl, equality-operator

I have a small perl script that needs to evaluate the equality of two parameters and a small return from the database.

```
my ($firstId, $secondId, $firstReturnedId, $secondReturnedId, $picCount);
my $pics = $dbh->prepare(qq[select id from pictures limit 10]);

$firstId = q->param('firstId');
$secondId = q->param('secondId');

$pics->execute or die;
my $picids = $pics->fetchall_arrayref;

$picCount = scalar(@{$picids});
$firstReturnedId = $picCount > 0 ? shift(@{$picids}) : 0;
$secondReturnedId = $picCount > 1 ? pop(@{$picids}) : $firstReturnedId;
```

Here, a quick look at my debugger shows that $picCount = 1 and $firstReturnedId = 9020 and $secondReturnedId = 9020. However, they are both denoted as

```
ARRAY(0x9e79184)
0 9020
```

in the debugger so when I perform the final check

```
my $result = (($firstId == $firstReturnedId) && ($secondId == $secondReturnedId)) ? 1 : 0;
```

I get $result = 0, which is not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is denoted as "`ARRAY(...) 0 9020`"?  `$firstId` and `$secondId`?  If so, you should probably give us more information about where those values are coming from.

Comment: $firstId and $secondId are what are coming back as arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBI::fetchall_arrayref` returns a reference to a list of "row results". But since there could be more than one value in a row result (e.g., your query could have been `select id,other_field from pictures`), each row result is also a reference to a list. This means you have one more dereferencing to do in order to get the result you want. Try:

```
$picCount = scalar(@{$picids});
if ($picCount > 0) {
    my $result = shift @{$picids};
    $firstReturnedId = $result->[0];
} else {
    $firstReturnedId = 0;
}
if ($picCount > 1) {
    my $result = pop @{$picids};
    $secondReturnedId = $result->[0];
} else {
    $secondReturnedId = $firstReturnedId;
}
```

or if you still want to use a concise style:

```
$firstReturnedId = $picCount > 0 ? shift(@{$picids})->[0] : 0;
$secondReturnedId = $picCount > 1 ? pop(@{$picids})->[0] : $firstReturnedId;
```

Comment: I could have sworn I had tried doing just that but I guess not. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!